# How to get value from a DIV element using 'this'

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the ID number so that later I can use it in jQuery POST. The ID number is in the variable called `data.results[i].id`. How can I get the ID number into the jQuery POST below.

```
for (var i in data.results) 
{ 
  document.getElementById("list-canvas").innerHTML += "<div id='list_element" + 
    data.results[i].id + "' value=" + data.results[i].id + 
    " class='list_element_class'>" +
    "<div id='list_image'>" +
    "<div id='actual_image'>" + data.results[i].feature_image +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>";

  $('.list_element_class').on('click', this.id, function(){
    $.post('sql_p.php', {id : this.value }, function(data)
           {
      $("#left_2").hide();$("#left_3").show();
      document.getElementById("left_3").innerHTML = data;
    });
  });
}
```

There is nothing wrong with "this.id" as it does contain the given element ID, but the "this.value" comes back as undefined.

Comment: I think you are trying to do `this.textContent` instead of `this.value`, which works for text input element and text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `div` does not have a `value`. Only form elements do.

You can use a `value` attribute, but you have to get it with `getAttribute` (`.attr('value')` in jQuery)

Comment: Could you help out with how to implement the getAttribute.

Comment: `.attr('value')`. Unless `value` is somehow reserved. In this case, use a different attribute name.

Comment: I used it as this: $.post('sql_p.php', {id : this.attr('value') }, function(data)   The code is not working. Is this the correct way to use .attr ?

Comment: @Sandor use `$(this).text()` (_in jquery_) or `this.textContent` (_in javascript_)

Comment: It does not have to be called "value" or the method I am presenting. Basically any way I can get the ID number out and use it in the POST ?

Comment: Maybe `$(this).attr('value')`

Answer (score 0):

The first "this" refers to the element where your code run.
The second one refers to the element of $('.list_element_class')

try this:

```
var element = this;
$('.list_element_class').on('click', element.id, function(){
  $.post('sql_p.php', {id : element.value }, function(data)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked eventually:

```
     $('.list_element_class').on('click', this.id, function()
         {
         var tid = $(this).attr("value");
         $.post('sql_p.php', {id : tid }, function(data)
              {
              $("#left_2").hide();$("#left_3").show();
              document.getElementById("left_3").innerHTML = data;
              });
           });
```